# Multiple rules for the same url?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I've a use case where i need an endpoint

```
/api/v1/resources
```

that should be public and private at the same time. What does it mean?
If basic authentication is provided, i would like to perform the authentication as usual, that stores the stuff in SecurityContextHolder.

On the other hand, if there is no authentication provided, i would also like to allow the request.

I tried a bunch of stuff overriding

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
```

without luck. if i do

```
http.authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/api/v1/resources").permitAll()
```

and i call the endpoint with basic auth, it obviously ignores and despite the request go ahead, i don't have the auth information that i need to forward to another service.

if i do

```
http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
```

i get that endpoint working and having the basic auth result stored so i can forward the information, but then i get 401 when calling it without authentication.

Is there a way I can apply multiple rules to the same endpoint? Or something similar to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

For now, the only way i found to achieve this was adding a custom filter before the whole chain that checks for the Authorization Header, and if there no header, i inject the header in the request as an attibute(i need to wrap the request object to override the getHeader method to search for attributes if the header is missing so i can retrieve that header afterwards).

Comment: @dur that didn't solve my problem. By doing this, i'm still missing the authorization object in SecurityContextHolder despite the fact that i'm sending the propert Basic Authentication Header.

Comment: i understand that. The problem i'm having with your approach is that, if i put `.permitAll().and().httpBasic()` in a single route and then i hit that route with or without Authorization Header, it behaves in the same way... the request go ahead but i always have the Authentication object in `null`.